# Is the complexity of std::set constructor listed on cppreference incorrect?

Tags: c++

On this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set, it says:

> 4-5) log(N) where N = std::distance(first, last) in general, linear in N if the range is already sorted by value_comp().

Isnt that incorrect? I would expect it to be O(NlogN) in the general case because you are inserting elements N times into the tree and each insertion takes logN time.

Comment: if its is already sorted the complexity is worse :D. Cannot be correct

Comment: question is whether its a mistake in the standard or on cppref

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what the standard says about the complexity [[set.cons]p4](https://wg21.link/set.cons#4.sentence-1):

> *Complexity*: Linear in *N* if the range [`first`, `last`) is already sorted with respect to `comp` and otherwise *N* log *N*, where *N* is `last - first`.

So it seems like a typo on cppreference, but someone can fix it: https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Template:cpp/container/constructor_ord&section=2&action=edit